# How is table populated in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My company has a table in a db, which is populated with some store numbers. It's updated daily with data for the past 30 days (running window). The table was set up by someone who's no longer at the company.

My question is, how to find out where the data comes from? I.e. what populates the table and how?
I've tried right-clicking on the table and clicking "**View Dependencies**" in SSMS, but it doesn't list anything.

I need to find out where the data comes from, since the table has started to show considerably fewer observations than before.

The server is running **SQL Server version 13** and I'm using **SSMS 18**.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring database activity with SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events? ApplicationName might reveal something.

Comment: Check for scheduled SQL Server Agent jobs, perhaps running an SSIS package.

Comment: @PeterSmith Logins? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @RuudHelderman - thanks. Several entries from ApplicationName=SQLAgent, so I assume there must be a job somewhere.

Comment: @DanGuzman According to the Server Profiler, there seems to be some SQL Agent job. Trying to figure out more. Thank you

Comment: @Artem, just a quick word of caution about running Profiler against an active prod server. Be sure events are adequately filtered as to not impact performance. I've seen rowset traces crash a busy server.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the heads up. I'm currently looking into how to setup the Profiler properly.

Comment: Given the other comments mine is not now helpful so I've deleted it.

Comment: @Artem, you might consider learning Extended Events since Profiler is deprecated. SSMS 18 includes a XEvent Profier node under Object Explorer with a couple of quick sessions. For example, right-click on Standard and click launch session. You can also add filters to that session by selecting the trace properties under `Management-->Extended Events-->Sessions-->QuickSessionStandard`.

Comment: Anything that can connect to your database could be populating it. But often it is indeed an SSIS package but it could be anything. It could be a .Net console app, a Java app, MSMQ, a web application... anything

Answer (score 0):

Run the query below, it will tell you if your table is used in any function, procedure, trigger or view on the database.
Then you can run the same query again on the found objects off course.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%'
```

This will only tell you if this table name is used in any object on your database, not if its used from any application.
But at least it will tell you any function/procedure names that you need to look for in your applications

Comment: The query returns 0 rows. So might be from a SSIS package then?

Comment: Most probably some application or service is populating your table directly. Try monitoring your database using the profiler and look for the column ApplicationName